# Android-Texture mapping a sprite on OpenGL ES looks pixelated/poor quality

Tags: android, opengl-es, sprite

I am trying to texture map a png file I made on Photoshop and it does not bear the same quality of the image as the original png file.

The png file is 128 x 128 in pixels. I have tried to map this using GL_LINEAR and GL_NEAREST and both do not seem to give the quality that I am looking for.

With this issue in mind, when I try to animate the texture by translating it up and down (like a pacman 2d game), I begin to see some "blurry pixelated artifact issues" where the pixels seem to not be fixed and just plain bad. This problem is worse on GL_NEAREST. What I want is to have a texture mapping that is as perfect as the original PNG file and be able to translate the image through the screen without any "flickering" issues. Here is a snippet of the code that loads the texture.

```
in = fileIO.readAsset(fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        setFilters(GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

public void setFilters(int minFilter, int magFilter) {
    this.minFilter = minFilter;
    this.magFilter = magFilter;
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
}
```

I don't have any fps issues. This problem seems to be purely on how I am texture mapping my sprite. I would like to post a screenshot but I'm not allowed to as I'm a new user.

Edit: The problem seems to be more profound when I want to texture map it to a very small size. If I texture map it to fill the screen, the texture quality looks better.